# Windows server power off button and blocked sessions

Tags: session, windows-server-2008-r2, shutdown, blocked

We have one windows Server 2008 R2 installation and we need the power button to trigger the server's shutdown procedure.

Generally this works as expected, but when there's a blocked session the shutdown does not happen.

I have googled this requirement wide and far, but I have been unable to find anything related.

Comment: It is the physical button I am talking about, not the start menu one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://www.7tutorials.com/advanced-users-task-creation-task-scheduler) to create a task triggered by the power button event (I'm not sure about the `EventID`, perhaps 109 or 1074).

The task will call the [`shutdown`](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/p/shutdown-command.htm) command:

```
shutdown /s /d p:0:0
```

- `/s` shutdown command to the local computer
- `/d` this records the reason for the shut down (`p` is planned and `0:0` indicates an "Other" reason)